# Fill na values with 0 if column is in a list python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with +10 columns and I want to fill NaN values with 0 for some of them but not for all. How could I do that properly?

I created a list with the columns I dont want to fill nan values and I tried:

```
if df not in not_fill_list:
   df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

But it's not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not:

```
for c in [s for s in df.columns if s not in not_fill_list]:
    df[c].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to create a list of columns you want to fill:

`df[fill_list].fillna(0, inplace=True)`

You could create one from let list you have as follows:

```
fill_list = [col for col in df.columns if col not in not_fill_list]
```